# Calculate percentages across columns

Tags: r

So I have a data.frame in R studio I've made with the following columns

```
Site               sumofspecies1       sumofspecies2      totalspecies
uniquesite         500                 1000               1500
uniquesite2        1000                500                1500
```

I'd like to make a data frame that changes these values to be

```
Site               sumofspecies1       sumofspecies2      totalspecies
uniquesite         33.3%               66.6%              1500
uniquesite2        66.6%               33.3%              1500
```

Or something to that effect it seems easy enough however I'm having a lot of difficulty finding a similar case online or in the documentation

Cheers

Comment: If you want to calculate proportions column-wise, you can do `df[2:3] <- sapply(df[2:3], prop.table)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate_at(vars(2:3), funs(paste0(round(100*./sum(.), 1), "%")))
#         Site sumofspecies1 sumofspecies2 totalspecies
#1  uniquesite         33.3%         66.7%         1500
#2 uniquesite2         66.7%         33.3%         1500
```

Comment: Hi akrun, really appreciate the help! I forgot that I am using 3 species and 1 total and adapting the function to take vars(2:4) does not sum up percentages correctly. I don't see an issue with the code however do you know why this would be a problem?

Comment: @BenHili  You may need to update your post with another example and expected output as I didn't get a clear idea what you wanetd

Comment: Sorry if that post was confusing, I've managed to correct the issue it was just a simple mistake on my part. Thanks!